# I want to Create a Table Layout Dynamically ! Help me in this

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have created a Table Layout named table and I am trying to add the table reference id (R.id.table)

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
```

using the following and populate by table with text Views

The application gets crashed when i am executing this.. I debugged and inspected the Code 
carefully I saw the **R.id.table value is returning null** but there is **no compiler error**

Here is my table.xml, its a Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrol"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dummy"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tablerow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is my approach is right or wrong .. Whether i have to refer the Row id of the Table table ?? Is there any way to create Dynamic Table layout ??

I was googling all around for this but i dont fine any suitable examples for this.. can anybody help me in this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your xml and code? Basically if findViewById returns null that means there's no view with such id in the XML file. Compiler will not complain because syntactically it's all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be useful for you

in first.xml you create

```
<TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</TableLayout>
```

in second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/spinnerEntryContactPhoto" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinnerEntryContactPhoto" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/dd"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/spinnerEntryContactName" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:singleLine="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/spinnerEntryContactName1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</TableRow>
```

In your class

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, table, false);
table.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title states you're adding a table dynamically, but your code shows you're trying to reference a table that already exists?

It will be null if the layout which is currently displayed does not contain that table. In which case, you should reference that layout and then call findViewById, e.g `theLayoutWhichContainsTheView.findViewById(...)`.

If you truly want to create a dynamic `TableLayout` you want to use this code:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
```

You'd then need to add a `TableRow` to the `TableLayout` and then add `Views` to the `TableRow`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity,etc have you set the ContentView. It should be set in `onCreate` method like below.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.callaction);

  TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);}
```

Please do a clean & rebuild of your project, then it will regenerate the R.java file (which is gen folder) as well.

Comment: what I have mentioned is not the way to create a Table-Layout dynamically. Because when I read your question I felt that you are looking for a Table-Layout which is in a XML file.

Comment: I am sure the error is not with the R.java Build file .. If its so it will show the compiler error..

Comment: Please post your XML file. It will be helpful.

Comment: just change the android:id="@+id/table" into android:id="@+id/table1" or something else, clean & rebuild the project and see.

Comment: I just dropped down and chose . . Horizantal Linear Layout now its working fine.